# JS if else vs if and continue within a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, continue

I have some code that looks like this:

```
for(...){
    if(something){
        ...;
        continue;
    }
    for(...){
        ...;
    }
}
```

Now I was wondering if it would be a better solution to replace the `continue` with an `else` block that contains the second loop.

Thank you for your opinions

Comment: Define what "better" means for you. JS interpreter does not care and would run either similarly.

Comment: Entirely opinion-based. Some people don't like `continue`, `break` etc. I don't like deep nesting and long scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting in an else block would make the code functionally equivalent, yes. As for whether it's better? Like others have said, the JS interpreter won't care - it'll handle it the same way regardless. The only important thing then is human readability.

If the internal for loop is long and complicated and contains lots of other stuff, then using *continue* may well be a better option, as it clearly states to the reader that it doesn't matter what else is in the loop, it'll go to the next iteration. using an if/else means the user has to confirm that there is no code further down that will execute after the if/else.

In another situation, using *if/else* might be better because using continue might end up in code duplication, or later maintenance might add a couple of lines to the end of the loop, thinking that every iteration will pass through it (always make your code as idiot-proof as possible if someone else may be modifying it later!).

Ultimately it comes down to opinion and coding standards (if it's part of a larger project then it should match what is elsewhere as much as possible). Do whatever makes the code most understandable to you. Ask someone else to have a look at the end product if you can, see if they have a different opinion to you - it's always easier to read your own code, having someone else look at it can highlight things that aren't quite as clear as you think they are!

Answer (score 0):

How zerkms noticed, js interpreter will run this code similarly.

In my opinion, code with `if..else` statement becomes more readable, and also `continue` statement could be used, when there is nothing to do at this step of loop.